# Objective C to C# Equivalent

Tags: c#, arrays, objective-c

I've got this statement I'm trying to convert form objective c to c#:

```
NSData *blockData;

if(valid)
{
    if(sendingLast) 
    {
         blockData = rawFirmwareData;
    }
    else 
    {
        int startingPos = (currSensor.firmwareBlockIterator * 
                (ourCurrentSensor.firmwareBlockSize - headerSize));
        blockData = [rawFirmwareData subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(startingPos, 
                    rawFirmwareData.length - startingPos)]
    }
}
else 
{
    blockData = [rawFirmwareData 
                subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange((currSensor.firmwareBlockIterator * 
               (currSensor.firmwareBlockSize - headerSize)), 
               (currSensor.firmwareBlockSize - headerSize))];   
}
```

I've tried translating it to the following, but I'm not sure if I've done it properly:

```
byte[] blockData;

if(valid)
{
    if(sendingLast) 
    {
        blockData = rawFirmwareData;
    }
    else 
    {
        blockData = new byte[(currSensor.firmwareBlockSize - headerSize)];                            
        Array.Copy(rawFirmwaredata, (currSensor.firmwareBlockIterator * 
                  (currSensor.firmwareBlockSize - headerSize)), blockData, 0, 
                  (currSensor.firmwareBlockSize - headerSize));
    }
}
else 
{
    blockData = new byte[(currSensor.firmwareBlockSize - headerSize)];
    Array.Copy(rawFirmwaredata, (currSensor.firmwareBlockIterator *       
               (currSensor.firmwareBlockSize  - headerSize)), blockData, 0, 
               (currSensor.firmwareBlockSize - headerSize));
}
```

I'm not sure if my array length is correct when I initialize it based on the starting and ending positions.